# Como acessar campos de uma classe mãe através de herança?

Tags: java, classes, herança

Simplificando o que eu quero dizer, suponhamos que tenho uma classe Mãe:

```
public class Mãe {

    private String nome;   // Declarando o campo privado nome

    public Mãe(String _nome) {

        nome = _nome;   // Definindo o campo nome 

    }

}
```

Agora, a classe filha:

```
public class Filha extends Mãe {   // Extendendo da classe Mãe

    public Filha(String _nome) {

        super(_nome);   // Chamando o construtor da classe Mãe

    }

}
```

Portanto, no construtor da classe `Filha` eu chamei o construtor da classe `Mãe`, certo? Então como eu faria, na classe `Filha`, para acessar o campo `nome`, da classe `Mãe`? Eu deveria por esse campo como público?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá! Sim, o super serve para acessar o construtor da classe Mãe. Para acessar os atributos você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public class Filha extends Mãe {   // Extendendo da classe Mãe   
    public Filha(String _nome) {
        System.out.println(this.nome) // Pega o atributo nome que está na classe mãe
    }  
}
```

Porém o atributo deve estar como `protected` ou `public` para que possa ser acessado diretamente em classes filhas. O modificador de acesso `private` permite o acesso direto apenas a classe que declarou o atributo. O `protected` permite também para classes herdeiras e o `public` libera o acesso a todas.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado por sua resposta!